# Hide node if user has viewed it

Tags: views

I have a restaurant with a Drupal site and would like to post coupons for patrons to use.  They would have to create a user account to view it.  The coupon would be an image field and if a user wants to use it they would click use coupon and it would hide it from that user only.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you displaying the coupons (I assume an image in a node) in a view?

Comment: More than likely it would be an image in a node.

Comment: Please confirm. Is this a "Coupon" node, where the entire node needs to be hidden? Or is the node still available but the image is not visible?

Comment: Entire node hidden would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

You can with [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) + [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

In `/admin/structure/flags/add` add flag of "Content" and call it something like "use coupon" flag.

I presume your Nodes teasers are listed in view. So in Views:

- In Relationships add "Content flag"

  - Uncheck include only flagged content
  - Flag: Slect your flag
  - By: Current User

[image]

- In Filter Criteria add "Flagging" and select not flagged.

To prevent from viewing node directly by typing the url, in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules):

- In `/admin/config/workflow/rules` create Rule with action of "Flagging is viewed".
- Add Action of "Page redirect" and send them to some custom /url that says you already redeemed this coupon. (Create a basic page for this)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the statistics module to see if the user has view the content. Note the statistics module has some performance implications.